# Using ProcessBuilder to execute a python script with command line options

Tags: java, python, processbuilder

in order to execute a python script(which has several command line parameters)  from Java, I am trying to use is the following java code

```
String[] command = {"script.py", "run",
                    "-arg1", "val1", 
                    "-arg2", "val2" ,          
                    "-arg3" , "val_31 val_32",
       };

ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );
Process process = probuilder.start();
```

For instance I intend to execute the following command:

```
./script.py run -arg1 val1 -arg2 val2 -arg3 val_31 val_32
```

note that the parameter arg3 takes a list of parameter values.

The problem I am facing is that I did not find a way to pass a list of values to the parameter arg3.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me some hints in order to tackling my problem.

I already did a search but I could not find a suitable answer for my needs, if someone find the right link please let me know.

Best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give them as separate strings in the array, instead of combining the last two into `"val_31 val_32"`:

```
String[] command = {"script.py", "run",
                    "-arg1", "val1", 
                    "-arg2", "val2" ,          
                    "-arg3" , "val_31", "val_32",
       };
```

Otherwise it will escape the space in between `val_31` and `val_32` because you are telling it that they're a single parameter. Incidentally, you can also use the `varargs` constructor and skip having to create an array, if you want:

```
ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( "script.py", "run",
                    "-arg1", "val1", 
                    "-arg2", "val2" ,          
                    "-arg3" , "val_31", "val_32");
```